# Async Task error Android

Tags: android

I am developing an app which is connecting to a web service and show the data in a list view.i can show the data successfully [i have used a custom list view and to show data i have use custom adapter class which is extended by Base Adapter] . now i am trying to connect to another web service when an accept button clicked [which is inside the list view]. i have developed the methods which is get the String Response from the service and those are working well.[I have tested through my app].

My problem is, i want to show some progress dialog while connecting to the service and show the response using a toast message. i have use `AsyncTask` class for that. first i have just run a thread and make it sleep for some time.that was perfectly worked with my `AsyncTask`. But when I am calling the web service using it [within `doInBackground()`] I got an error:

> Activity com.jsonlist.jsonlist.ViewList has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41814e38 that
>   was originally added here android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity
>   com.jsonlist.jsonlist.ViewList has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41814e38 that
>   was originally added here at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:374) at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)

My code is below:

This method is inside my Adapter class

```
        public void dialogshow(final String Date,final String Start,final String End){

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Confirm your Action!");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes Confirm!!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {




                    //Toast.makeText(mContext, "Yes clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                    new ShowResponceForAccept().execute();



                }
              })
              .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        alertDialogBuilder.show();

    }
```

when I press "YES" button from the dialog box. it should call my `AsyncTask`.

here is my `AsyncTask`

```
    public class ShowResponceForAccept extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();


        pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Sending Request", "getting Responce.", true, false);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //  ShortList sendandget = new ShortList();
    //  String resp = sendandget.getResponceFromServer(Appid, null, Uid);

        ShortList sendandget = new ShortList();
        String resp = sendandget.getResponceFromServer(Appid,"",Uid);
        //Thread.sleep(10000);
        //String x="Your Request Accepted";

        return resp;
        //return x;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         pDialog.dismiss();


         String x = resp;



         Toast.makeText(mContext, x, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }


}
```

this also in the same Adapter Class.

can anyone help me please...?

EDIT

here my full Adapter Class

```
public class NewsRowAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

static Dialog dialogs;
private static final String STIME = "StartTime";
private static final String END = "EndTime";
private static final String DATE = "Date";
private Context mContext;
private Activity activity;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
int resource;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

String Uid = MainActivity.confirm;
String getDate;
String getStartTime;
String getEndTime;
String Appid;
    //String response;
    //Context context;
    //Initialize adapter
    public NewsRowAdapter(Context ctx,Activity act, int resource,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        super();
        this.resource=resource;
        this.data = d;
        this.activity = act;
        this.mContext = ctx;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());


    }

    public void showFirstDialog(final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Confirm your Action!");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("You Have Similar Kind of Appoinments!! Do you wanna Show them ?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                    //Toast.makeText(mContext, "Showing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dialogpop(list);


                }
              })
              .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        alertDialogBuilder.show();

    }

    public void dialogshow(final String Date,final String Start,final String End){

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Confirm your Action!");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes Confirm!!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {




                    //Toast.makeText(mContext, "Yes clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                    new ShowResponceForAccept().execute();
                    dialog.dismiss();


                }
              })
              .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        alertDialogBuilder.show();

    }

    public void dialogshowForReject(){

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Confirm your Action!");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes Confirm!!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {


                    //Toast.makeText(mContext, "Yes clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    new ShowResponceForReject().execute();
                //  loadListAgain();


                }
              })
              .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        alertDialogBuilder.show();

    }  



    public void showDuplicateDialog(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){

        //CharSequence[] cs = list.toArray(new CharSequence[list.size()]);


        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        LayoutInflater infl = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        View view = infl.inflate(R.layout.dialog_list, null);

        ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialogList);

        //NewsRowAdapter nw = new NewsRowAdapter(mContext, activity, R.layout.dialog_row, list);

        SimpleAdapter sim = new SimpleAdapter(mContext, list, R.layout.dialog_row,  new String[] { STIME,END, DATE }, new int[] {
                R.id.stime2,R.id.etime2, R.id.blank2});
        lv.setAdapter(sim);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "item clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });



        /*ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                  android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, android.R.id.text1, Names);*/

        alertDialogBuilder2.setView(view)
        /*alertDialogBuilder2.setAdapter(sim, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "item clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        })
        */



        .setPositiveButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Accepted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        alertDialogBuilder2.show();
    }



@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {


    View vi = convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,null);


        final TextView firstname = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.fname);
        final TextView lastname = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.lname);
        final TextView startTime = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.stime);
        final TextView endTime = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.etime);
        final TextView date = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.blank);
        final TextView hidID = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.hidenID);
        final TextView hidAppid = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.HidAppoinmentID);
        final ImageView img = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);


        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song =data.get(position);

        firstname.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_PROP_FNAME));
        lastname.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_PROP_LNAME));
        startTime.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_STIME));
        endTime.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_ETIME));
        date.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_DATE));
        hidID.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_HID));
        hidAppid.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_HIDApp));

        String theUrl = song.get(MainActivity.TAG_IMG);

        if(theUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("null")){
            Bitmap bImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.propic);
            img.setImageBitmap(bImage);


            //ViewList v = new ViewList();
            //v.handleImage(theUrl, img);
        }
        else{

            /// replace these codes


        Profile pc = new Profile();

        Bitmap map =pc.downloadImage(theUrl);
        img.setImageBitmap(map);







       // imageLoader.DisplayImage(theUrl, img);
        }
        Button accept = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btnAccepted);
        accept.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final int x = (int) getItemId(position);
                /*Intent zoom=new Intent(mContext, Profile.class);
                zoom.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
                zoom.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mContext.startActivity(zoom);*/

                // get the intent from the hashmap check if there is similar date and time.
                //then store them in a list or array.

                 getDate = (String) date.getText();
                 getStartTime = startTime.getText().toString();
                 getEndTime = endTime.getText().toString();
                 Appid = hidAppid.getText().toString();

                ShortList sh = new ShortList();

                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> duplicateList; 
                duplicateList=sh.getDuplicated(getDate, getStartTime, getEndTime);

                if(duplicateList.size()>1){
                    //dialogshow(getDate,getStartTime,getEndTime);
                    showFirstDialog(duplicateList);
                }
                else{
                    dialogshow(getDate, getStartTime, getEndTime);

                }




            }
    });


        Button reject = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btnReject); 
        reject.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // get User ID  and get request ID
                //then call the method getResponceFromServerForReject()

                dialogshowForReject();
                //MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
                //
                //ma.new JSONParse().execute();








            }
        });


        vi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String getPname = hidID.getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "view clicked: "+getPname , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //get the id of the view
                //check the id of the request
                //call the web service acording to the id





                Intent zoom=new Intent(parent.getContext(), Profile.class);  
                zoom.putExtra("PatientID", getPname);
                parent.getContext().startActivity(zoom);



            }
        });

        return vi;


}

public void dialogpop(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){

    dialogs = new Dialog(activity);
    dialogs.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_list);
    dialogs.setTitle("Select One");



    ListView listView = (ListView) dialogs.findViewById(R.id.dialogList);

    //SimpleAdapter sim = new SimpleAdapter(mContext, list, R.layout.dialog_row,  new String[] { STIME,END, DATE }, new int[] {
    //        R.id.stime2,R.id.etime2, R.id.blank2});

    Adapter_For_Dialog nw = new Adapter_For_Dialog(mContext,activity, R.layout.dialog_row, list);
    listView.setAdapter(nw);



    dialogs.show();

}


public class ShowResponceForAccept extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();


        pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Sending Request", "getting Responce.", true, false);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //  ShortList sendandget = new ShortList();
    //  String resp = sendandget.getResponceFromServer(Appid, null, Uid);

        ShortList sendandget = new ShortList();
        String resp = sendandget.getResponceFromServer(Appid,"",Uid);
        //Thread.sleep(10000);
        //String x="Your Request Accepted";

        return resp;
        //return x;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         pDialog.dismiss();


         String x = resp;



         Toast.makeText(mContext, x, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }


}


public class ShowResponceForReject extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        /*pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        */

        pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Sending Request", "getting Responce.", true, false);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //  ShortList sendandget = new ShortList();
    //  String resp = sendandget.getResponceFromServer(Appid, null, Uid);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String x="Successfully Rejected";

    //  return resp;
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String x) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         pDialog.dismiss();
```

/*           if(resp.equalsIgnoreCase("-1")){
                 Toast.makeText(mContext, "Accepted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

```
             //REFRESH THE LIST



         }
         else{

         Toast.makeText(mContext, "Rejected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }*/

         Toast.makeText(mContext, x, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }


}


public void loadListAgain(){

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = null;
         String TAG_DATA = "d";
         String TAG_OBJ_1 = "Appointment";
         String TAG_OBJ_2 = "PatientProfile";
         String TAG_PROP_FNAME = "FirstName";
         String TAG_PROP_LNAME = "LastName";
         String TAG_STIME = "StartTime";
         String TAG_ETIME = "EndTime";
         String TAG_DATE = "Date";
         String TAG_HID = "PatientPersonId";
         String TAG_HIDApp = "AppointmentId";
         String TAG_IMG = "ImageURL";
    JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();

    String caregiverID = MainActivity.confirm.toString();

    JSONObject param = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject job =  new JSONObject();
    try {
        param.put("caregiverPersonId", caregiverID);
        job = jp.getJSONFromUrl(param, MainActivity.url);

        JSONArray androids = job.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);


        //JSONObject appt= new JSONObject(json.getString("d"));


       for(int i = 0; i < androids.length(); i++){
          JSONObject c = androids.getJSONObject(i);

          // Storing  JSON item in a Variable

          JSONObject jobs  = c.getJSONObject(TAG_OBJ_2);

          String url = jobs.getString("ImageURL");



          String firstName = jobs.getString(TAG_PROP_FNAME);
          String lastName = jobs.getString(TAG_PROP_LNAME);

          JSONObject job_two  = c.getJSONObject(TAG_OBJ_1).getJSONObject("DayTimeSlot");

          String start = job_two.getString(TAG_STIME );
          String end = job_two.getString(TAG_ETIME);


          String Ldate = job_two.getString(TAG_DATE);
          String ackwardRipOff = Ldate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");
          Long Ldat = Long.valueOf(ackwardRipOff);
          Date date = new Date(Ldat);
          String strdate = (String) DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yy", date);


          JSONObject toHid = c.getJSONObject(TAG_OBJ_1);

          String Hid = toHid.getString(TAG_HID);




          JSONObject job_three  = c.getJSONObject(TAG_OBJ_1);
          String AppoinmentID =  job_three.getString(TAG_HIDApp);


          // Adding value HashMap key => value

          HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

          map.put(TAG_PROP_FNAME, firstName);
          map.put(TAG_PROP_LNAME, lastName);
          map.put(TAG_STIME , start);
          map.put(TAG_ETIME, end);
          map.put(TAG_DATE, strdate);
          map.put(TAG_HID, Hid);
          map.put("ImageURL", url);
          map.put("AppointmentId", AppoinmentID);

          oslist.add(map);

          //duplicate = new JSONObject();


          //reult.putStringArrayListExtra("map", oslist);
          //startActivity(reult);


          /*reult.putExtra("arraylist", oslist);
          startActivityForResult(reult, 500);*/

            Intent reult = new Intent(activity,ViewList.class); 
            reult.putExtra("arraylist", oslist);
            activity.startActivityForResult(reult, 500);

          }

        }
    catch(JSONException c){
        c.printStackTrace();
    }
}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return data.size();

}



@Override
public Object getItem(int possision) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return possision;
}



@Override
public long getItemId(int possision) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return possision;
}
```

}

Comment: please some one help me....

Answer (score 0):

Use `YourActivity.this` instead of `activity` in

`AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);`

and

`pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Sending Request", "getting Responce.", true, false);`

Hope this helps.

Comment: i cant use it because im inside the Adapter class  :(

Comment: post your adapter class

Comment: @Piyush Gupta

C my Edited Question i have posted my adapter class

Comment: @GishanthaDarshana : Where have you declared your activity?

Comment: @Siddharth Vyas

i have pass it as a parameter when i set the adapter to my list view

Answer (score -1):

Add `dialog.dismiss()` after calling AsyncTask

```
new ShowResponceForAccept().execute();
dialog.dismiss();
```